# Tableau - Segmenting data into 3 sections

Tags: grouping, tableau-api, segment

I have a few months worth of retail data and am looking to do a general analysis on any potential lift in sales.

How can I group or segment the data so it's easier to few the target date ranges.

For example, if I have 3 months of data and want to group each month in their own section, how do I do so?

Thanks,
Cafe

Answer (score 1):

You could use any date/datetime dimension in two ways:

- Truncated Date (blue one)
- Date Part (green one)

more info on how to set it up you will find [here](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/dates_levels.html).
If you will use Date Part on the month level all data is segmented into groups which consist only of entries from this particular month. This allows you to add another dimensions below month in order to go deeper with analysis.

If you would like to create rather custom date ranges (ex. 03.09 - 23.09) you could use [Sets](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/help.html#sortgroup_sets_create.html). Just drill down to day, select range you are interested in and create a new set. If you would like to compare few different sets, use calculated field to create a single dimension which will be grouping data based on information to which set single data entry belongs.

```
IF [Set 1] THEN 'Name of first set'
ELSEIF [Set 2] THEN 'Name of second set'
ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Comment: Okay. Since it's a custom date range for each.. I believe making sets would be ideal. I will try this out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to **create a calculated field which does this grouping for you**. I have followed this up with an example using an arbitrary dataset containing dates to mimic the scenario which OP mentioned in the comments.

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
|   Date    | Hour of Day | Count |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| 9/20/2016 |           6 |   100 |
| 9/21/2016 |           7 |    23 |
| 9/22/2016 |          15 |    58 |
| 9/23/2016 |          13 |    78 |
| 9/24/2016 |           3 |    32 |
| 9/25/2016 |          12 |    54 |
| 9/26/2016 |           0 |    32 |
| 9/27/2016 |          23 |    11 |
| 9/28/2016 |          11 |    10 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

I am loading this dataset into Tableau. I create a calculated field called 'Date Grouping' with the following formula. The [Date] in this formula is the Date from my dataset. You can switch this out with whatever your date field is called.

```
IF DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'09-22-2016'), [Date]) < 1 THEN 'Before 9/22' 
ELSE (IF DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'09-25-2016'), [Date]) < 1 THEN '9/22 - 9/25'
ELSE 'After 9/25'
END)
END
```

This creates a new column as shown below (I copied this from the data source in Tableau)

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
|   Date    | Date Grouping | Count | Hour of Day | Number of Records |
+-----------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
| 9/20/2016 | Before 9/22   |   100 |           6 |                 1 |
| 9/21/2016 | Before 9/22   |    23 |           7 |                 1 |
| 9/22/2016 | Before 9/22   |    58 |          15 |                 1 |
| 9/23/2016 | 9/22 - 9/25   |    78 |          13 |                 1 |
| 9/24/2016 | 9/22 - 9/25   |    32 |           3 |                 1 |
| 9/25/2016 | 9/22 - 9/25   |    54 |          12 |                 1 |
| 9/26/2016 | After 9/25    |    32 |           0 |                 1 |
| 9/27/2016 | After 9/25    |    11 |          23 |                 1 |
| 9/28/2016 | After 9/25    |    10 |          11 |                 1 |
+-----------+---------------+-------+-------------+-------------------+
```

This calculated field can now be added to colour/size to create a grouping within the chart as shown below
[image]

**Tight Bound on the Range**

As you has mentioned your ranges in the comments, I have edited the calculated field query to create a tight bound instead of an open bound. The [Date] in this formula is the Date from my dataset. You can switch this out with whatever your date field is called.

```
IF (DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'05-08-2016'), [Date]) > 0 AND DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'06-13-2016'), [Date]) < 0) THEN '5/9 - 6/12' 
ELSE (IF (DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'06-12-2016'), [Date]) > 0 AND DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'07-18-2016'), [Date]) < 0) THEN '6/13 - 7/17' 
ELSE (IF (DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'07-17-2016'), [Date]) > 0 AND DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'08-22-2016'), [Date]) < 0) THEN '7/18 - 8/21' 
ELSE 'Out of Range' END) END) END
```

Input Table (dates have been modified to suit the date range mentioned)

```
+-----------+-------------+-------+
|   Date    | Hour of Day | Count |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
| 5/9/2016  |           6 |   100 |
| 5/10/2016 |           7 |    23 |
| 5/11/2016 |          15 |    58 |
| 6/12/2016 |          13 |    78 |
| 6/13/2016 |           3 |    32 |
| 6/14/2016 |          12 |    54 |
| 7/17/2016 |           0 |    32 |
| 7/18/2016 |          23 |    11 |
| 7/19/2016 |          11 |    10 |
| 8/21/2016 |          23 |    11 |
| 4/9/2016  |          15 |    58 |
| 8/22/2016 |          13 |    78 |
+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

After adding the calculated field 'Range'

[image]

Comment: @CafeRacer I would suggest creating a calculated field which assigns these groups. I have edited my answer to suit this.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Just so I understand your comments can you please let me know if this is correct. For my above date ranges would the code operate in this fashion.  `code` IF DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'06-13-2016'), [Date]) < 1 THEN 'Before 6/13' 
ELSE (IF DATEDIFF('day', DATEPARSE("MM-dd-yyyy",'07-18-2016'), [Date]) < 1 THEN '6/13 - 7/17'
ELSE 'After 7/17'
END)
END Also - can you explain the [Date] within the code?

Comment: Date range would be Range #1 5/09/2016 - 6/12/2016 Range #2 6/13/2016 - 7/17/2016 Range #3 7/18/2016 - 8/21/2016

Comment: @CafeRacer [Date] is the field you want to check for the [Date] from your dataset. Whichever field in your dataset is the date can be switched out with [Date]. And yes, the calculated field you have provided will give you the 3 buckets as you expect. If you need a lower bound on the Range#1 and a upper bound on Range#3, you would need to add that in too.

Comment: @CafeRacer I have edited the solution and added the tight bound query with an example. This works.